# generate unique big integer for a tables column Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, unique, bigint

How would I generate in Laravel a unique biginteger for a database table column on save.

I have

```
------------------------------
id  | banner_id  | title
------------------------------
1   | 2348779    | some title
------------------------------
2   | 2312779    | some title2
------------------------------
```

where `id` is my `primary key` and `banner_id random unique bigint`

Comment: Why the separate value instead of relying on the primary key (which is presumably already unique and automatically generated)?

Comment: you are right but I take over some old structure what was designed not properly and the old system should run behind so I do not have big flexibility to make major changes on table

Comment: The SERIAL column type would seem appropriate if it's possible to convert it (SERIAL is a BIGINT with unique and auto increment properties). Otherwise, looking into something like microtime() may be your best bet to minimize collisions.

Comment: yes microtime() thats it, this one is a good advise!! I will try with that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you need integer:

```
floor(
   microtime() 
   * rand(10,100) // range may be different
   * time() 
);
```

or;
create a numbers_table

```
| id |

ALTER TABLE `numbers_table` auto_increment = 10000000000;
```

insert a record and get last insert id! and use it for banner_id

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
$number = rand(9999, 9999999);
```

Comment: yes but I have to validate this number exists or not.